# Which AWS api "logs" user activity in general

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, web-services

I am trying to create an APP in .NET that will generate a report, where I can see what services have been in **use** and their **consumption**.
For example, if an employee creates a VM in **AWS** where can I see when he did it?

Comment: What have you tried, what errors are you getting?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please go through `AWS cloudtrail` - [link] [https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_IN&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=cloudtrail_b&sc_content=cloudtrail_e&sc_detail=aws%20cloudtrail&sc_category=cloudtrial&sc_segment=159807218538&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=IN&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!159807218538!e!!g!!aws%20cloudtrail&ef_id=EAIaIQobChMIpODM8IuT4QIViQsrCh2EcQUbEAAYASAAEgJfbPD_BwE:G:s]